# How to create Fastlane Action to return filtered git commits

Tags: git, fastlane

I need to create my own Fastlane action to return git commit messages with custom filter.

This is git code:

```
git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --no-merges --invert-grep --grep="\[Gitlab\ CI\]" --pretty=format:"%ad - %an, %s" --date=short
```

I need Fastlane action to return output of that.

I tried to find some tutorials online how to create it, but I cannot find any helpful info for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but have you seen this ...
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/changelog_from_git_commits/

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it. I just wanted to have more control when filtering comments and create custom Fastlane action for that. This action allows only to choose between "only merge commits" and "without merge commits".
But thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use changelog property in your lane:

```
changelog = git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --no-merges --invert-grep --grep="\[Gitlab\ CI\]" --pretty=format:"%ad - %an, %s" --date=short
```

[3 ways to provide notes](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/beta-deployment/#release-notes) - the second one is the solution